# Is it possible to reuse a GnuPG key in another installation?

Tags: gpg-agent, pgp, openpgp

I have a GPG key which I use to sign and submit packages to Launchpad.

Is it possible to reuse that key in another installation, or do I always have to create a new key for the new installation of a GNU/Linux operating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than copying the `~/.gnupg` folder, you can create an export of your secret keys and then import on the new install, e.g.

```
$ gpg --export-secret-keys --output mykeys
```

Then on the new system:

```
$ gpg --import mykeys
```

(**note:** you will need to know the password associated with the keys to import them)

By exporting and importing, you allow `gpg` to handle any version/format differences between differing versions of `gpg` on the different installs.

You can use the `--export` option for your stored public keys in the same manner. (though I have found not including the public keys as a good way to purge all the old, non-used keys that have been collected over the years if you don't explicitly need them)

Answer (score 0):

Copy ~/.gnupg to the new system